# Differentiability and inflection point

Tags: calculus, analysis

Does a function need to be differentiable at least 3 times in order to have an inflection point?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think that if the 3rd derivative is zero , the 2nd derivative must have been a constant, so the function exhibits no change of concavity.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $f(x):=x\cdot|x|$ as an easy example.

Answer (score 1):

No, consider the function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \sin(x) & \text{if } x\leq \pi/2 \\ 2-\sin(x-\pi)^2 & \text{if }x >\pi/2 \end{cases}$$

[image]

In black: $f$, in red: $f''$.

Answer (score 0):

Inflection point means when a curve changes its concavity, the function may not be differentiable but may have inflection point. But it should be differentiable near that point, to define change in concavity.

Comment: I asked the question assuming that any function must have at least a third non-zero derivative before it can have a point of inflection.

Answer (score 0):

No.  $x^{1/3}$ is not even differentiable once at $x=0$ but it has a point of inflection there.